# Underlying variety of $\mathbb{G}_m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

I try to understand what is meant by the expression that $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ is the ***underlying variety*** of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$  over the field $K$ .

I know that

- $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the algebraic group over $K$ whose group action is given by multiplication
  $$\mu(x,y)=x \cdot y ~~~ \text{   and   } ~~~ \iota(x)=x^{-1}$$
- we can define $\mathbb{G}_m =$ Spec$(K[T, T^{-1}])$, i.e. it is an affine variety
- $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the functor sending a $K$-scheme $X$ to the multiplicative group of invertible global sections of the structure sheaf, i.e. $\mathbb{G}_m(X)= \mathcal{O}_X(X)^*=K^*$

  But what exactly is meant by the above expression? Thank you for your explanations!

(EDIT: In this post [How is the multiplicative group an algebraic variety?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340152/how-is-the-multiplicative-group-an-algebraic-variety) they even use it as an identity.)

Comment: The statement just says that when we regard it as a variety, we get that (so this amounts to identifying the spec of $K[T,T^{-1}]$ with $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: Sorry - yes, of course, it is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algebraic group is a quadrauple $(G, m, i, 1)$ where $G$ is an algebraic variety over a field $k$, and 
$$m : G \times_k G \to G,  i : G \to G, 1 : \mathrm{Spec}(k) \to G$$ are morphisms of varieties, satisfying some commutative diagrams as [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object).
So the algebraic variety underlying an algebraic group $(G, m, i, 1)$ is simply the algebraic variety $G$.

By the way, it is not quite exact to say that an algebraic group is « a group that is also an algebraic variety ». What is true is that for any $k$-algebra $R$, the set $G(R)$ has a group structure (and actually the functor of points $R \mapsto G(R)$ factors through a functor $k$-$\sf Alg$ $\to \sf Grp$). The problem is that the set underlying $G \times_k G$ is *not* the set $|G| \times |G|$ (where $|G|$ is the set underlying the variety $G$), and it is [difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322188/how-to-compute-the-topological-space-of-fibered-product-of-schemes) to compute in general. 
Therefore, a group structure on the set $|G|$, given in particular by a multiplication map $ \mu : |G| \times |G| \to |G|$, will not give you a morphism $m : G \times_k G \to G$ required in the definition of algebraic group (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596622/is-a-group-object-in-the-category-of-algebraic-schemes-over-k-an-honest-group?rq=1)).